# Is there any difference in memory layout for composition vs inheritance?

Tags: c++, oop, c++11, inheritance, memory

```cpp
struct A
{
    int a, b, c;
    int fa() { /*something*/}
};
    
struct B1 : A
{
    int a1, b1, c1;
    int ba() { /*something */}
};
    
struct B2
{
    A a;
    int fa() {a.fa();}
    int a2, b2, c2;
    int ba() { /*something */}
};

void main()
{
    B1 b1;
    B2 b2;
    //something
}
```

Will `b1` and `b2` have the same layout in memory? Also, in class `B2`, did I basically did everything that is done by the compiler when I use inheritance?

Comment: `B1` has an implicit conversion to `A` which `B2` does not.

Comment: Of course there is a difference in memory layout for these. But the question isn't memory efficiency or such, but what's better suitable semantically. So you shouldn't take that into account for a design descision.

Comment: This is easy to check with the debugger or with `printf("%p...`

Comment: They could have the same layout. But if they did, it's not something you are allowed to rely on.

Comment: The answer to this depends on why you want to know this information. Do you want to know if the compiler does something similar to this as a way of implementing inheritance? Or do you want to know if `B1` and `B2` have the same layout because it would allow you to treat a pointer to one as a pointer to another?

Comment: As written, they probably have the same layout but minor changes to definition of `A` and it will not be true anymore. Typically, you should prefer `B2` over `B1` if you don't need to access protected member of `A` or redefine a virtual method.

Comment: @Justin the former